# jQuery mmenu open submenu from outside the menu structure

Tags: jquery, mmenu

I'm trying to figure out a way to trigger a submenu from outside the mmenu structure.

Opening a submenu with a link directly refering to the mmenu id, doesn't work:

```
<div class="content">
   <a href="#mm-2">Open submenu from here</a>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9FdXv/40/

Comment: Please try to add as much info as possible in your post to avoid relying on external links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the id `external` or whatever you like to your external anchor. Also add an id to the `ul` constituing your "80% werken" menu. (In this example I used `80_sub`). Now add the following to your js script:

```js
$('#external').click(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault(); //Avoid mmenu to get the click and close
    var api = $("#my-menu").data( "mmenu" );
    api.openPanel( $("#80_sub") );
});
```

We are manually manipulating the menu using the [API](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/documentation/core/api.html).

Edit: [Working example based on your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9FdXv/44/).

Comment: thanks @GSystemGlitch works great, but the content div is dynamically loaded, if I add the anchor in a the content page, your solution doesn't work. How should I get that to work?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 1):

Check This fiddle for open a menu dynamically.I've user trigger event of the menu.

You can add id of the menu as `data-href` in a tag like the following

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-href="#mm-2" class="open-dynamic"><span>Open the submenu "80% werken" from here</span></a>
```

You can generate all menu external link by adding different id in the a tag.

And the following script will work for open a menu.

```
 $(document).on("click", ".open-dynamic", function () {                    
                    $(document).find("[href='" + $(this).attr("data-href") + "']").trigger("click");                   
            });
```

[Check This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaydipshingala/9FdXv/45/)